# JasperServer 404 on css resources

Tags: jasperserver

I've just installed a new JasperServer v6.2 on Redhat 6.2 compiling from source.  I've had no problems up to this point with the server.  All documentation worked fine, until I started the server.  When trying to login all the css resources give me 404 errors.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Installation Steps:

```
1.) ./js-ant clean-config
2.) ./js-ant gen-config
3.) ./js-ant build-ce
4.) ./js-ant import-minimal-ce
5.) ./js-ant deploy-webapp-ce
```

---

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/login.html

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/_themes/7F5573FA/importExport.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/_themes/7F5573FA/common/base.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/_themes/7F5573FA/common/layout.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/_themes/7F5573FA/manageTenants.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/_themes/7F5573FA/common/js_reset.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.